# Data format in ERDAS IMAGINE 2014?

Tags: erdas-imagine

I performed radiometric correction analysis on Landsat 8 image ( format: integer unsigned 16 bit) in ERDAS IMAGIN 2014.

However, the output image would be created if I could select format: float 32 bit.

It was not created in unsigned 16 bit.

My question is, was this float 32 bit output correct or not?